# Django rest framework dynamic view class selection

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am looking for a way dynamically selecting (based of feature flag value) a view class for the same endpoint

The problem I'm trying to tackle is having different behaviour (permission, serializer, search fields etc..) for certain feature flag value, and I would like to make the selection in a single point, not for every attribute separately

Is there a way doing so?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to create a common view and in that view, call your actual views on the basis of your flags.

```
def middle_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if flag:
       return actual_view1(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
       return actual_view2(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What is the middle view? Is it a class? Who calls the method?